# ExoPlayer throwing OutOfMemory on simple video playback from local raw files on Compose

Tags: android, video, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer

I've encountered a crash on ExoPlayer playback on lower Android versions, like **8.1, 9** (both emulators and phisical phones), while it's working on emulator **API 31** without issues. **Using Compose for all of this**

Since i couldn't find the issue on the main project, even trying to create a blank project with a simple ExoPlayer and isolate the functionality **throws the same error**.

Tried using a lot of stuff, different ways to load the source, with/without media source, with different schemes, adding load balancer with `.setPrioritizeTimeOverSizeThresholds(false)`, setting stuff in **remembers/without remembers**, and so on.

The output is very random, depending on when OutOfMemory is being thrown:

- video starts playing a bit then crashes
- black screen -> crash
- video stuck -> crash
- sometimes even getting some weird coroutine errors, with like 1/20 reproduction rate

Code from below is the sample app with a basic player.
Have to mention **test app works on Phisical phone without a crash**, while when adding the same **code on real app with same dependencies**, it's crashing (i guess other stuff loading for main app cause the OOM error).

**Video is 11s length and 11,8MB in size, MP4 format**

```
@Composable
fun VideoView(video: Int = R.raw.app_onboard_full) {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val exoPlayer = remember(context) {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .setLoadControl(DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
                .setPrioritizeTimeOverSizeThresholds(false)
                .build())
            .build()
            .also { ep ->
                ep.playWhenReady = true
                ep.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_OFF

                val res = RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(video)

                val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(context)
                val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(res))

                ep.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
                ep.prepare()
            }
    }

    val lifecycleOwner = rememberUpdatedState(LocalLifecycleOwner.current)

    DisposableEffect(
        AndroidView(
            factory = {
                PlayerView(context).apply {
                hideController()
                useController = false
                resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM

                layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
                    player = exoPlayer
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )
    ) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { owner, event ->
            when (event) {
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> {
                    exoPlayer.pause()
                }
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> {
                    exoPlayer.play()
                }
                else -> {}
            }
        }
        val lifecycle = lifecycleOwner.value.lifecycle
        lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

        onDispose {
            exoPlayer.release()
            lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}
```

Everything resulted in the same OutOfMemory error.

Since i couldn't find the issue on the main project, even trying to create a blank project with a simple ExoPlayer and isolate the functionality **throws the same error**.

Tried using a lot of stuff, different ways to load the source, with/without media source, with different schemes, adding load balancer with `.setPrioritizeTimeOverSizeThresholds(false)`, setting stuff in **remembers/without remembers**, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue within my app. I stop and release the player when the view gets to the `onPause` lifecycle state. I play the video when the lifecycle gets to `onResume` and is not playing yet.

I have fixed it with the following DisposableEffect

```kotlin
    DisposableEffect(lifecycle) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME && !exoPlayer.isPlaying) {
                exoPlayer.play()
            } else if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE) {
                exoPlayer.stop()
                exoPlayer.release()
            }
        }

        lifecycle.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

        // When the effect leaves the Composition, remove the observer
        onDispose {
            lifecycle.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
```

The reason the OOM happens is because the compose view gets recreated/redrawn with certain actions. So the compose view will keep creating players and therefore adding videos to the memory.